# How to throw an error in this.state.forEach statement in react

Tags: reactjs, exception

I read a bit about error throwing but I don't really understand how to throw an error for the specific code in this code below when react complains about that it is undefined.

Do I use the componentDidCheck and if yes how do you exactly do it? The code where it catches the error is below and it is the forEach where it blows up

```
class Subject extends React.Component {

state = {
    subject: [],
}

render() {
    var products = [];
    var index = 0;

    this.state.subject.forEach(product => {
        subjects.push(<Product
            key={index} subjectName = {this.state.subjects[index].name} 
            subjectPrice = {this.state.subject[index].salePrice}
            subjecttId = {this.state.subject[index].itemId}
        />)
        index++;
 });
```

Comment: Do you want to show a fallback UI when the error happens or do you want to avoid error altogether?

Comment: Sidenote: `product` variable inside `forEach` already has your product, you don't need to use `index`

Comment: Either way is fine @BoyWithSilverWings

Comment: @Kevin Have you tried below solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are uneccessarily making complex logic. You have to utilize .map in your case. It’s just simple with .map

Don’t use index as key instead use itemId from each product as key. Index should be always second option if you don’t have unique id in the data then go for index otherwise don’t.

Since you are already doing .forEach or .map you no need to use index to get product details, because .map or .forEach will give you each object from products array. You can just access product.itemId and others like that

The reason you get undefined error may be because the products state is initially undefined or empty array and that’s why you get that error

So do check whether products is an array and contains list of objects by checking its length and then do .map

You no need to track index, you no need local array variable to push Product component into it

Below is the most efficient way of rendering Product component in simple and clean way

.map without return

```
   render() {
   const { products } = this.state;
   return(
        <div>
           {Array.isArray(products) && products.length > 0 && products.map(product=> (
    <Product key={product.itemId} productName = {product.name} productPrice = {product.salePrice} productImage = {product.thumbnailImage} productId = {product.itemId}
    />))}
    </div>
     )
  }
```

.map with return

```
  .map without return

   render() {
   const { products } = this.state;
   return(
        <div>
           {Array.isArray(products) && products.length > 0 && products.map(product=> {
    return <Product key={product.itemId} productName = {product.name} productPrice = {product.salePrice} productImage = {product.thumbnailImage} productId = {product.itemId}
    />})}
    </div>
     )
  }
```

If you do like above you won’t get into errors. I posted this answer to correct you because you are making things complex

You can check error and info that componentDidCatch gives you and check these two return fallback UI accordingly